# Dependency injection won't work when GraphQL ObjectGraphTypes in multiple assemblies

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate, graphql.net

I have defined several GraphQL ObjectGraphType and queries in several projects. All of these projects has dependency to asp.net boilerplate GraphQL project. It return error **"Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: "No component for supporting the service was found"** when i tried to call any graphQL queries.

**Exception Stacktrace**

```
Sample.Types.ProductPagedResultGraphType was found ---> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Sample.Types.ProductPagedResultGraphType was found
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, Arguments arguments, IReleasePolicy policy, Boolean ignoreParentContext)
   at Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection.ScopedWindsorServiceProvider.GetServiceInternal(Type serviceType, Boolean isOptional) in D:\Github\castle-windsor-ms-adapter\src\Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection\ScopedWindsorServiceProvider.cs:line 55
   at GraphQL.Types.Schema.<CreateTypesLookup>b__56_2(Type type)
   at GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddTypeIfNotRegistered(Type type, TypeCollectionContext context)
   at GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.HandleField(Type parentType, FieldType field, TypeCollectionContext context)
   at GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddType(IGraphType type, TypeCollectionContext context)
   at GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.Create(IEnumerable`1 types, IEnumerable`1 directives, Func`2 resolveType, IFieldNameConverter fieldNameConverter)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at GraphQL.Types.Schema.get_AllTypes()
   at GraphQL.Instrumentation.FieldMiddlewareBuilder.ApplyTo(ISchema schema)
   at GraphQL.DocumentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

It works when all those queries and ObjectGraphType are in  1 project which is asp.net boilerplate GraphQL project.

In order to allow GraphQL ObjectGraphType and queries in multiple projects instead of putting all in the asp.net boilerplate GraphQL project, I have made the following changes:

1. I have created a new QueryContainer (ExtQueryContainer.cs) to extend the original QueryContainer.cs
2. I have modified the original QueryContainer by removing the sealed keyword from the class in order to allow the newly created QueryContainer to inherit the original QueryContainer.
3. I have created a new GraphQL schema (GraphQLSchema.cs) which reference the newly created ExtQueryContainer

**ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs (In asp.net boilerplate GraphQL project)**

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddAndConfigureGraphQL(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(
            x => new FuncDependencyResolver(x.GetRequiredService)
        );

        services
            .AddGraphQL(x => { x.ExposeExceptions = DebugHelper.IsDebug; })
            .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
            .AddUserContextBuilder(httpContext => httpContext.User)
            .AddDataLoader();
    }
}
```

**ExtQueryContainer.cs**

```
public sealed class ExtQueryContainer : QueryContainer
{
    public QueryContainer(RoleQuery roleQuery, UserQuery userQuery, OrganizationUnitQuery organizationUnitQuery, ProductQuery productQuery)
        : base(roleQuery, userQuery, organizationUnitQuery)
    {
        AddField(productQuery.GetFieldType());
    }
}
```

**GraphQLSchema.cs**

```
public class GraphQLSchema : Schema, ITransientDependency
{
    public GraphQLSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)
    {
        Query = resolver.Resolve<ExtQueryContainer>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `AddGraphTypes` for each assembly:

```cs
var productGraphAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProductPagedResultGraphType));

services
    .AddGraphQL(x => { x.ExposeExceptions = DebugHelper.IsDebug; })
    .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped) // Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() is implicit
    .AddGraphTypes(productGraphAssembly, ServiceLifetime.Scoped) // Add this
    .AddUserContextBuilder(httpContext => httpContext.User)
    .AddDataLoader();
```

You may be able to register `IGraphType` types separately:

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProductPagedResultGraphType));

foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && typeof(IGraphType).IsAssignableFrom(x)))
{
    services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(type, type, ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/server/blob/3.4/src/Core/GraphQLBuilderExtensions.cs